# Is there any way to pass a variable while initializing an enum instead of passing actual value in java?

Tags: java, enums

I need to pass a class variable to an enum while initializing it .But the class variable is not accessible while initializing the enum . So how can this be achieved ?

I tried passing variable of another class, same class where the enum resides . Both didn't work.

```
public class ComponentConstants {

    public Constants constants = Constants.getInstance();
    enum FIELDS_RESOURCES {
        //instead of text i want to use constants.data_type.text. But I was not able to.

        SourcetType(true, "text", "Source Type", "source_type", 255, false); //No I18N
        private VOCFIELDS_RESOURCES(boolean isCustomField, String data_type, String field_label, String api_name, int length, boolean isVisible) {
            this.isCustomField = isCustomField;
            this.data_type = data_type;
            this.field_label = field_label;
            this.api_name = api_name;
            this.length = length;
            this.isVisible = isVisible;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above I want to use the value from constants since if there is any change there ,it should be reflected in my code too . Single point of constants , but i was not able to use it. How can this be achieved and why is it not allowing to use other variables? Thanks!

Comment: Nested enums are implicitly static, meaning they don't have access to the instance fields of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public enum Enumeration {

        Test(Constants.a, Constants.b); // can refer to constant "a" & "b" static variables

        private final String a;
        private final String b;

        Enumeration(String a, String b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    public static class Constants {

        static String a = "a";
        static String b = "b";
    }
}
```

If you utilize `static` fields as constants, they can be referenced within enumeration constructors. More details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-values) regarding enum fields.